# Fetch the first element from the array with fake api 'myjson.com'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In the 'myjson.com' website, I created a url 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/17qwmf' which returns an array to me. How to get an element with 'id: 1', the first element from the array. I'm trying to do it this way: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/17qwmf/1' but I'm getting an error.

From the documentation it looks like it can be done: http://myjson.com/api

Code here: [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bq2p1u)

```
class Items extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {   
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = 1;
    axios.get
      axios({
        url: `https://api.myjson.com/bins/17qwmf/${id}`,
        method: "GET"
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          items: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div > 

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is no a router for getting an element by it id, you have to filter got array

```
class Items extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {   
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = 1;
    axios.get
      axios({
        url: `https://api.myjson.com/bins/17qwmf`,
        method: "GET"
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          items: response.data.filter(item => item.id === id)[0] // you will get a first element of got array
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div > 

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It can be done. Look at the documentation. I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Look here: http://myjson.com/api

Comment: i've researched the documentation and it is not possible to create own ids, the service generates ids randomly

Answer (score 0):

Please check this `https://api.myjson.com/bins/17qwmf?id=${id} if you want to fetch only element with id that ur passed

Comment: It return all array